# Magento - Accessing Products Custom Attribute Value in Mage_Sales_Model_Order.php

Tags: magento

I'm trying to access the handling time for specific products through a custom attribute in Mage_Sales_Model_Order.php with `$handlingtime = $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('fig_handling_time');`

But everytime I send an order email i get the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object in /home/japena/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php on line 1320`

I've been researching all day, tried many different code and have come to the conclusion that I can't access the product `$this->getProduct()` or `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')` and I've also tried

`$_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());
$handlingtime = $_product->getData('fig_handling_time');`

`$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());`
`$handlingtime = $product->getAttributeText('fig_handling_time');`

`$handlingtime = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item['product_id'])->getAttributeText('fig_handling_time');`

`$handlingtime = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)->getAttributeText('fig_handling_time');`

Nothing seems to work any ideas I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**//First get the attribute id**

```
$audienceAttributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','session_audience');
//Now Load the attribute
$audienceAttribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($audienceAttributeId);
```

**//Now get the product collection that you want to use to fine the attributes values for.
//I wanted the attribute values for only grouped products. You could add category filters
and such**

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())
->addAttributeToSelect('session_audience')
->addAttributeToSort('session_audience', 'asc')
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
```

**//Now get the product ids for the collection**

```
$productCollectionIds = $productCollection ->getAllIds();
```

**//Now we query the data base to get the attribute values for the given product ids.
//NOTE that I am selecting from the catalog_product_entity_varchar table because this is the type of attribute I was using.**

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$select = $read->select();
$select->from('catalog_product_entity_varchar')
->where('attribute_id = ?', $audienceAttributeId)
->where('entity_id IN (?)', $productCollectionIds );

//print_r($select->__toString());die();

//Now get the ids for the attribute values.

$result = $read->query($select);
$attributeOptionIds = array();
while($row = $result->fetch()){
$attributeOptionIds = array_merge($attributeOptionIds, explode(',', $row['value']));
}
array_unique($attributeOptionIds);
//print_r($audienceOptions);die();
```

**//Now get the actual values for the Ids as a Collection and do something with the values.**

```
$filteredAudienceCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
->setPositionOrder('asc')
->setAttributeFilter($audienceAttributeId)
->setStoreFilter($audienceAttribute->getStoreId())
->addFieldToFilter('main_table.option_id', array('in' => $attributeOptionIds))
->load();
```

Comment: How do I search for the `fig_handling time` attribute for the specific item being purchased?

Comment: ->addAttributeToSelect('session_audience') change with your custom attribute id